# How to redirect to application after login the twitter(iPhone settings page)?

Tags: iphone, ios, twitter

How can I back to the iPhone application after login the twitter?(See the image)

Is it possible to redirect from the settings page?

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't redirect from the Settings app, but if you want to redirect between other apps, you can use UrlShemes. [UrlShemes](http://www.idev101.com/code/Objective-C/custom_url_schemes.html)

Comment: Thank you. Any other way to get the user details from the twitter after login.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way of doing that, but an alternative would be opening the external link in a UIWebView, then you will always be in your app!

Comment: Thank you. Any other twitter api for get the user details. Is it possible to get the user email id.

Comment: No Twitter does not provide the users email address via the API.See the thread here on the twitter support forum: https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/1737

Answer (score 1):

NO you can not redirect back to your app. Apple does not provide any means to do this.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do that because that is not a standard iPhone functionality.

You can't redirect from one app to another, and Settings is an application like all the rest. Furthermore you can't change the behaviour of existing applications, each app is in a sandbox and is separate from others.

There is no need to do something like this and users don't expect that kind of behaviour.

Comment: Thank you. Any other twitter api for get the user details. Is it possible to get the user email id.