# Turn back to app after authorize Twitter Successful

Tags: ios, iphone, twitter

I config my app to use the **login by twitter** feature. But I cannot turn back to my app after authorize app success on safari. I saw another question with the same problem on stack overflow [use UrlShemes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13395514/how-to-redirect-to-application-after-login-the-twitteriphone-settings-page) but this not work with me(I don't have enough reputation to add comments to ask them into the accept answer).So please let me know: **If I can turn back to my app after authorize successful (like Facebook API can do)? If this is possible, so how to do this?**

Here is my code:

```
    self.twitter = [STTwitterAPI twitterAPIWithOAuthConsumerKey:Twitter_API_KEY
                                                 consumerSecret:Twitter_API_SECRET];
    [_twitter postTokenRequest:^(NSURL *url, NSString *oauthToken) {
        NSLog(@"-- url: %@", url);
        NSLog(@"-- oauthToken: %@", oauthToken);
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];

    } authenticateInsteadOfAuthorize:NO
                    forceLogin:@(YES)
                    screenName:nil
                 oauthCallback:@"sutrixsnowball://"
                    errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {
                        NSLog(@"-- error: %@", error);
                    }];// The "sutrixsnowball" is URL Schemes item into plist file
```

It just open the web page on safari like the image below (It's not a real url when I copy, so I post the image):

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note** For those still using STTwitter I would recommend switching over to Twitter's official SDK found [here](https://docs.fabric.io/ios/twitter/authentication.html)

### Original Post

You need to make sure that your oauthCallback is a scheme listed in your Apps plist. You could also use a cleaner reverse domain host scheme just to be super sure you never conflict with any other Apps.

So your App plist would look something like this:

[image]

Where I'm using **com.twitteroauthcallback.sutrixsnowball** as the URL scheme.

The you need to handle this callback in your app delegate. Something like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
    if ([[[url scheme] lowercaseString] isEqualToString:@"com.twitteroauthcallback.sutrixsnowball"] == NO) {
       return NO;
    }
    NSMutableDictionary *twitterParamsDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

    NSArray *queryComponents = [[url query] componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"];

    for(NSString *s in queryComponents) {
        NSArray *pair = [s componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];
        if([pair count] != 2) continue;

        NSString *key = pair[0];
        NSString *value = pair[1];

        twitterParamsDictionary[key] = value;
    }

    NSString *token = twitterParamsDictionary[@"oauth_token"];
    NSString *verifier = twitterParamsDictionary[@"oauth_verifier"];

    if (token && verifier) {
        [self setOAuthToken:token oauthVerifier:verifier];
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;

}
- (void)setOAuthToken:(NSString *)token oauthVerifier:(NSString *)verifier {

__weak typeof (self)weakself = self;
[self.twitterAPI postAccessTokenRequestWithPIN:verifier
                                  successBlock:^(NSString *oauthToken, NSString *oauthTokenSecret, NSString *userID, NSString *screenName) {
                                      [weakself.twitterAPI getUserInformationFor:screenName
                                                                    successBlock:^(NSDictionary *user) {
                                                                        ///we have an account
                                                                    } errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {
                                                                        /// error
                                                                    }];

                                  } errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {
                                      ///error
                                  }];
}
```

You will notice that the success block for the `postAccessTokenRequestWithPin:` conveniently passes back a token and a secret. Looking at STTwitterAPI you will see the following constructor:

```
+ (instancetype)twitterAPIWithOAuthConsumerKey:(NSString *)consumerKey
                                consumerSecret:(NSString *)consumerSecret
                                    oauthToken:(NSString *)oauthToken
                              oauthTokenSecret:(NSString *)oauthTokenSecret
```

So if you keep those values somewhere on the device you can login to twitter on next startup:

```
/// Next app launch
STTwitterAPI *twitterAPI = [STTwitterAPI twitterAPIWithOAuthConsumerKey:consumerKey consumerSecret:consumerSecret oauthToken:oauthToken oauthTokenSecret:oauthTokenSecret];
        [twitterAPI verifyCredentialsWithSuccessBlock:^(NSString *username) {
            /// we still good to go
        } errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {
            /// token has expired. User needs to login again
        }];
```

### EDIT

It turns out than in order to work STTwitter requires that the oauthCallback look something like this

```
oauthCallback:@"<YOUR_URL_SCHEME>://twitter_access_tokens/"
```

Comment: `NSString *token = d[@"oauth_token"];` where I can get `d`? And please explain the purpose of `postAccessTokenRequestWithPIN` and `setOAuthToken` you use here?

Comment: Answer has been updated and the postAccessTokenRequest is used so that we can retrieve the OAuth Tokens and get the user. Once you have the tokens you can use them to login again. will update my answer

Comment: After authorize success, my app even not call the function:`- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation`. it just open the `mobile.twitter.com` on safari as before.

Comment: what does your app plist look like under URL types?

Comment: I change as you're recommend: `com.twitteroauthcallback.sutrixsnowball` and `URL identify is: com.sutrixsnowballapp`, I aslo place the break point into this function but it didn't met the break point.

Comment: Yes, I had set the callback url(If not set this,When I call the login api then I cannot go to safari to authorize my app). I set this for an URL(website of my company)

Comment: @haatlee its a shot in the dark but try changing your code for the oauthcallbackURL to read oauthCallback:@"com.twitteroauthcallback.sutrixsnowball://twitter_access_tokens/

Comment: `changing your code for the oauthcallbackURL to read oauthCallback:@"com.twitteroauthcallback.sutrixsnowball://twitter_access_tokens/` it work for me(without those function above,after authorize success then I also can go back to my app). Many thanks for your help.

Comment: @haatlee thats great to hear, I will have to take some time out to find where i got that from but my first guess is from the demo project. But great to hear it worked!

Comment: still i am unable to get back to my app

Comment: @PatelJigar Perhaps ask a new question. Otherwise take a look at Twitters official SDK. I would not recommend using STTwitter anymore

Comment: then what can i use for login with twitter in objective-c?? @DanielGalasko

Comment: I can't get redirect in my app after login with twitter in safari using STTwitterAPI 
In my info.plist I set urlscheme = http://xxxx.me
In my twitter app I set callback url =  "http://xxxx.me"

Any one can help me ?

Comment: @parth as you will see in the first line I would suggest you use Twitters official SDK :)

Comment: @DanielGalasko We have the plan to integrate Twitter SDK in future. For now we can't remove STTwitter library. Can you help me on this?

Comment: unfortunately not @parth I would recommend going to STTwitter on GitHub or making the migration to the official API  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯