# Change User Follow/Unfollow using STTwitter

Tags: ios, xcode, twitter, sttwitter

I initially staretd with twitter-fabrc but as their was not much documentation about how to extend the one-click login to access twitter sdk, shifted to STTwitter. Here i understand the login flow and getting user tweets but how do access the Rest API Endpoints https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public  to make/destruct follow/unfollow relationships. Or suggest me a better way to go about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following `STTwitterAPI` methods:

```
// POST friendships/create
- (void)postFriendshipsCreateForScreenName:(NSString *)screenName
                                  orUserID:(NSString *)userID
                              successBlock:(void(^)(NSDictionary *befriendedUser))successBlock
                                errorBlock:(void(^)(NSError *error))errorBlock;

// POST friendships/destroy
- (void)postFriendshipsDestroyScreenName:(NSString *)screenName
                                orUserID:(NSString *)userID
                            successBlock:(void(^)(NSDictionary *unfollowedUser))successBlock
                              errorBlock:(void(^)(NSError *error))errorBlock;
```

Comment: Thanks @nst. btw, is the webView(callback url) method the only way to grab an access token (as the twitterAPIOSWithFirstAccount returns only the username) .. as access token seems neccessary to take actions on follow/unfollow

Comment: You can login the way you want. `[STTwitterAPI twitterAPIOSWithFirstAccount]` returns an instance of `STTwitterAPI` on which you can use the methods I mentioned.

Comment: with the webView method .. the callback is sending me to your demo app which also resides on the device - that implies that if there are 2 apps on a device using STTwitter with this url, the first installed one will open first. Moreover in this case it opens the webView and everything is good but while returning back it goes to safari then goes to your demo app. Plz suggest me a solution here - Do we need to  construct our own url scheme or is there a simpler solution.

Comment: The demo app implements the `myapp://` URL scheme. Just use another one for your own app.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27289386/turn-back-to-app-after-authorize-twitter-successful for instructions if needed