# Twitter Oauth through Twitter application iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter-oauth

I'm using STTwitter for twitter Oauth in iOS. Following is the URL used to redirect to the browser...

```
https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_callback_confirmed=true&oauth_token_secret=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXHas0lAxA3&force_login=1&oauth_token=YYYYYYYYYYYYYY
```

Is it possible to redirect to the iOS Twitter application instead of redirecting to browser for performing Oauth? If so what should be the URL for redirecting?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [callback URL](https://github.com/nst/STTwitter#callbacks-urls) with a custom URL scheme for your app.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27289386/turn-back-to-app-after-authorize-twitter-successful/27289762#27289762).